# convert string to unsigned char str

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to convert a string into a unsigned char *. And i've been running in circles.  My program prompts the user for a lastname which i take in as a string.  I am then hashing the string into an integer using djb2. which takes an unsigned char * as a parameter. The goal of my program is to create a hash table using chaining to handle collisons.

```
unsigned long djb2(unsigned char *str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

    return hash;
}
```

my code is as follows atm.

```
void insert(LinkedList<Person>* HashList1[], LinkedList<Person>* HashList2[], int listSize)
{
    char * cstr;
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    cstr = new char [str.size()+1];
    strcpy (cstr, str.c_str());
    int hashBucket1 = djb2(cstr) % listSize;
}
```

Im getting an error with the above telling me that "Argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "unsigned char *" . Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Listen to the compiler.  In `insert` you are using `char*`.  Your `dbj2` function takes an `unsigned char *`.  Those are different types.  Why not change `dbj2` to take a `const string&` and modify `dbj2` to operate on strings?

Comment: Or, alternatively, you could change `djb2` to accept arguments of type `const char*`. Since your hash function does not actually *modify* the input, you are better of with a `const` argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have typing issues like this, it's a good indication that you are not using the language in the best way.  Going back and forth between strings and char*s in C++ is a [bad code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Modify `dbjc` to use a string:

```
unsigned long djb2(const string& str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;

    for(string::iterator it=str.begin();it!=str.end();it++) 
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + *it; /* hash * 33 + character */

    return hash;
}
```

This will greatly simplify your insert:

```
void insert(LinkedList<Person>* HashList1[], LinkedList<Person>* HashList2[], int listSize){
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    int hashBucket1;
    hashBucket1 = djb2(str) % listSize;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid modifying the djb2 as it was a function provided to us to impliment via our teachers.  I guess i'll ask her if i can change the hash function djb2.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to modify `dbjc` function, as suggested by @Steven Burnap.

If  you cannot change `dbjc` then cast `cstr` to `unsigned char *` in `dbjc` call:

```
void insert(LinkedList<Person>* HashList1[], LinkedList<Person>* HashList2[], int listSize){
        char * cstr;
        string str;
        cin >> str;
        cstr = new char [str.size()+1];
        strcpy (cstr, str.c_str());
        int hashBucket1;
        hashBucket1 = djb2((unsigned char *)cstr) % listSize; // <-- here is the change
}
```